# Where can I get a list of all MSIL codes and their hex values?

Tags: reverse-engineering, hex, cil

Does anyone have a list or chart of all MSIL codes and their corresponding hex values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) - in particular, I believe partition III is what you're after.

Comment: ah - beaten by the Skeet. such sweet sadness

Comment: If it's any consolation, I'm off to bed now. Enjoy a Skeet-free 6 hours :)

Comment: @jon Skeet, terrific!! Thanks a ton

Comment: Just wanted to say again, this is exactly what I needed.  Thanks for the obscure find Jon.

Answer (score 2):

The [canonical source](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm)

The MSDN help pages on the [constants used in Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.aspx) are also useful

I find [.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) invaluable for actually checking things myself though, especially with the simplistic but rapid response [snippy add in](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Snippy&referringTitle=Home).